# Java: How to get the return statement return all values

Tags: java

I  tried  write  a  table that  displays  the  taxable  income  for an  incremental taxable income from 50,0000 to  60,000  under  4  different  filing  categories.  Employing  a  method, the  return  statement in the code    only  printed  out one of the  four  filing categories columns. Please how can I  get the  remaining   columns printed  out?

```
public class TaxableIncome {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Taxable Income\t\t Single\t\t Married Joint\t\t MarriedSeerate\t\t HeadofaHouse");
       System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
       double Tincome;
       int profile=1;
       for(Tincome=50000; Tincome<=60000; Tincome+=50) { 
           System.out.println( Tincome +"\t\t" + computetax(profile, Tincome));
       }
    }

    public  static double computetax( int status , double income) {
        double tax;
        double single=0;
        double mjoint=0;
        double mseperate=0;
        double head=0;

        for(status=1;status<=4;status++) {
            if(status==1) {  
                tax = 8350*.10 + (33950-8350)*0.15 + (income- 33950)*0.25;
                single= tax;
            }
            if(status==2) {
                tax = 16700*0.10 + (income-16700)*0.15;
                mjoint = tax;
            }   
            if(status==3 ) {
                tax =  8350*0.10 + (33950-8350)*0.15 + (income-33950)*0.25;
                mseperate= tax;
            }
            if(status ==4){
                tax = 11950*0.10 + (45500-11950)*0.15 +(income-45500)* 0.25;
                head =tax;
            }    
        }
    return (single);
    }
}
```

Comment: Return an array, or an object containing all the values you need.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I  am on  a self study  track,  and  yet to  reach array and  objects  lessons.  Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating your value for `tax` four times, then discarding that and returning just the single value for `single`.

Move the loop on status out of `computetax` and into caller.

**EDIT: given that you're on a self-study course, here's a version that should work within your constraints.**

It still needs a lot of improvement, but will get you further.

`public class TaxableIncome {`

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Taxable Income\t\t Single\t\t Married Joint\t\t MarriedSeerate\t\t HeadofaHouse");
       System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
       double Tincome;
       int profile=1;
       for(Tincome=50000; Tincome<=60000; Tincome+=50) { 
           double single=computetax(1, Tincome);
           double joint=computetax(2, Tincome);
           double seperate=computetax(3, Tincome);
           double head=computetax(4, Tincome);
           System.out.println( Tincome +"\t\tsingle:\t" + single + "\tjoint:\t" + joint + "\tseparate:\t" + separate + "\thead:\t" + head);
       }
    }

    public  static double computetax( int status , double income) {
        double tax;
        double single=0;
        double mjoint=0;
        double mseperate=0;
        double head=0;

            if(status==1) {  
                tax = 8350*.10 + (33950-8350)*0.15 + (income- 33950)*0.25;
                single= tax;
            }
            if(status==2) {
                tax = 16700*0.10 + (income-16700)*0.15;
                mjoint = tax;
            }   
            if(status==3 ) {
                tax =  8350*0.10 + (33950-8350)*0.15 + (income-33950)*0.25;
                mseperate= tax;
            }
            if(status ==4){
                tax = 11950*0.10 + (45500-11950)*0.15 +(income-45500)* 0.25;
                head =tax;
            }    
        }
    return (single);
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved  loop on status into caller, and  I  returned tax, but  still the  output doesnt change

Comment: However, I like the solution by @OldCurmudgeon.

Comment: I've just noticed that you're passing `profile` into computetax where you expect `status`, so it's always just 1 in your test.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `System.out.print()` to output each value as they're calculated within `computeTax`, then do a `System.out.println();` to get a carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

You should roll all of the calculation results into their own object and return one of those.

```
static class TaxDetails {

    double single = 0;
    double mjoint = 0;
    double mseperate = 0;
    double head = 0;
}

public static TaxDetails computetax(double income) {
    TaxDetails details = new TaxDetails();
    details.single = 8350 * .10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 + (income - 33950) * 0.25;
    details.mjoint = 16700 * 0.10 + (income - 16700) * 0.15;
    details.mseperate = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 + (income - 33950) * 0.25;
    details.head = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 + (income - 45500) * 0.25;
    return details;
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Taxable Income\t\t Single\t\t Married Joint\t\t MarriedSeerate\t\t HeadofaHouse");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (double income = 50000; income <= 60000; income += 50) {
        TaxDetails tax = computetax(income);
        System.out.println(income + "\t\t" + tax.single + "\t\t" + tax.mjoint + "\t\t" + tax.mseperate + "\t\t" + tax.head);
    }
}
```